# yaml::BadFile Program Termination

Tags: ubuntu, g++, yaml, yaml-cpp

I have build yaml-cpp and then also did

```
make install
```

Now everything has been done and setup. 
Now, I have a c++ file, which is parsing a user agent string. 
I have used uap-cpp library from github for parsing, which has a dependency on yaml-cpp.

I have run this same c++ file on my mac machine with no issues. But when I run the same file on Ubuntu(linux), I get this error below.

```
cc-user-2154@CC-USER-2154:~/Desktop/cocubes/uap-cpp$ g++ example.cpp libuaparser_cpp.a -L /usr/local/lib/  -lyaml-cpp -lboost_regex -std=c++11
cc-user-2154@CC-USER-2154:~/Desktop/cocubes/uap-cpp$ ./a.out 
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'YAML::BadFile'
  what():  bad file
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Now an interesting thing happened. 
I ran command 
sudo apt-get install libyaml-cpp-dev

Now it throws an error on compilation. The error is

```
cc-user-2154@CC-USER-2154:~/Desktop/cocubes/uap-cpp$ g++ example.cpp libuaparser_cpp.a   -lyaml-cpp -lboost_regex -std=c++11
libuaparser_cpp.a(UaParser.o): In function `YAML::TypedBadConversion<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >::~TypedBadConversion()':
/home/cc-user-2154/Desktop/cocubes/yaml-cpp/include/yaml-cpp/exceptions.h:212: undefined reference to `YAML::BadConversion::~BadConversion()'
libuaparser_cpp.a(UaParser.o): In function `YAML::TypedBadConversion<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >::~TypedBadConversion()':
/home/cc-user-2154/Desktop/cocubes/yaml-cpp/include/yaml-cpp/exceptions.h:212: undefined reference to `YAML::BadConversion::~BadConversion()'
libuaparser_cpp.a(UaParser.o): In function `YAML::BadConversion::BadConversion(YAML::Mark const&)':
/home/cc-user-2154/Desktop/cocubes/yaml-cpp/include/yaml-cpp/exceptions.h:206: undefined reference to `vtable for YAML::BadConversion'
libuaparser_cpp.a(UaParser.o): In function `YAML::detail::node& YAML::detail::node_data::get<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::shared_ptr<YAML::detail::memory_holder>)':
/home/cc-user-2154/Desktop/cocubes/yaml-cpp/include/yaml-cpp/node/detail/impl.h:143: undefined reference to `YAML::detail::node_data::convert_to_map(std::shared_ptr<YAML::detail::memory_holder>)'
libuaparser_cpp.a(UaParser.o):(.data.rel.ro._ZTIN4YAML18TypedBadConversionINSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEEE[_ZTIN4YAML18TypedBadConversionINSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEEE]+0x10): undefined reference to `typeinfo for YAML::BadConversion'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Can you load the file with `std::ifstream`?

Comment: @JesseBeder yes I am able to load file with std::ifstream

Comment: Can you show that code? The only thing yaml-cpp throws `BadFile` for is if the file can't be loaded; see [here](https://github.com/jbeder/yaml-cpp/blob/4fb1c4b92bf8d94b32ebccdd890407d45b3bc794/src/parse.cpp#L35)

Comment: Okay this is very embarrassing, so it(yamltest.cpp) ran properly, I saw I was making a mistake in the filename of the file to be loaded. Edited the question and removed that part. 
@JesseBeder can you tell me why was yaml-cpp throwing a runtime error when I ran the example.cpp and after i ran "sudo apt-get install libyaml-cpp-dev" , it was throwing compile time error. Would be grateful for any information from you. Thanks.

Comment: That's a linker error, not a compiler error; you're probably getting a different version of yaml-cpp from that installation command.

Comment: @JesseBeder you are right. I updated everything and it works now. Thanks a lot! :D